# reactjs Redux, how to load data from redux onComponentDidmount while a first action is already sent

Tags: reactjs, redux

Working with redux for a few time now I am facing a configuration that's blocking me.

Here is my ComponentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(fetchPosts('trendings'));
    (this.props.message) ? dispatch(removeMessage('')) : '' ;
  }
```

the `dispatch(fetchPosts('trendings'));` fill a props.posts with specifics arrays inside.
The thing is, once this props.posts is filled, I need to use it to feed an other dispatch, but all of those actions in the ComponentDidMount.

And here is my problem, the second dispatch is call while the first one is in action.
I need to do it this way:

```
    var outputList = this.props.posts.items['output'];
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    if (typeof outputList !== "undefined") {
      outputList.map((item, i) => {
        dispatch(newOutput(item.MarkerName));
      });
```

I tried to put this code into `componentDidUpdate` but the problem is that this function will automatically trigger each time an action occurs, which I don't want.

Is there a way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `componentWillReceiveProps`, with a tweak:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.posts.length === 0 && nextProps.posts.length > 0) {
    /* Do stuff here */
  }
}
```

This way, it'll run the code only once, when the posts became from empty array to array with items. If re-render is necessary, you should do it in `shouldComponentUpdate` instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Kujira!